# how to add active link dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `<nav>` tag that contains my links in my page with it. It looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I am trying to dynamically add an `.active` class to the parent(`li`). of the link by using some jQuery. Which looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("nav a").each(function() {
        var hreflink = $(this).attr("href");
        if (hreflink.toLowerCase()==location.href.toLowerCase()) {
            $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

I believe that the reason for this is because my `hreflink` variable is returning something like this: `index.htm` and the `location.href.toLowerCase()` is returning this: `file:///c:/personal/theme/index.htm`

I am assuming that there is a better way of doing this. Would someone be able to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cut off the needy things and then compare.

Try like,

```
var currentLink = location.href;
if (hreflink.toLowerCase()===currentLink.substring(currentLink.lastIndexOf('/')).toLowerCase()) {
```

Comment: I see what you are doing here, but i believe that will just return `/index.htm`. Is there a way to strip the `/`?

Comment: @scapegoat17 then just go with `currentLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1`